# Spring WebMvcTest how to mock Authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have a controller with the following method. I get the `Authentication` from the method parameters and use it to get the principal.

```
@PatchMapping("/{employeeId}/present")
public PersonalDevelopmentPlan savePresent(@PathVariable int employeeId,
                                           @RequestBody PersonalDevelopmentPlan personalDevelopmentPlan,
                                           Authentication authentication) {
    EmployeeDetails details = (EmployeeDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    return pdpService.savePresent(employeeId, personalDevelopmentPlan, details.getEmployee().getId());
}
```

I then have this test case using `@WebMvcTest`

```
@Test
@WithMockUser
public void testSavePresent_returns_result_from_service() throws Exception {

    PersonalDevelopmentPlan pdp = new PersonalDevelopmentPlan();
    pdp.setEmployee(EMPLOYEE_ID);

    given(service.savePresent(eq(EMPLOYEE_ID), any(), anyInt())).willReturn(pdp);

    mvc.perform(patch(URL_WITH_ID + "/present").secure(true)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pdp)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.employee", Matchers.is(EMPLOYEE_ID)));
}
```

When i run this though, i get a `NullPointerException` on the following line:

```
EmployeeDetails details = (EmployeeDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Because authentication is null. I already annotated the test with `@MockUser` but still authentication is null. How do i mock authentication in the parameters of the controller method?

My test is annotated with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you customized the principal using UserDetails as EmployeeDetails?

Comment: @PatelRomil i'm not sure what you mean. I override `loadUserByUsername` in my `UserDetailsService` and return `EmployeeDetails` (which extends `UserDetails`) if that is what you are referring to?

Comment: yes I was referring the same

Comment: @PatelRomil alright, so what do i do to resolve this?

Comment: I have added the details in the answer, you might use `@WithUserDetails` or `@WithSecurityContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`@WithMockUser`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser)
This will use the principal on the Authentication is Spring Security’s User object

---

[**`@WithUserDetails`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withuserdetails)

While `@WithMockUser` is a very convenient way to get started, it may *not work* in all instances. For example, it is common for applications to expect that the `Authentication` principal be of a *specific type*. This is done so that the application can refer to the principal as the custom type and reduce coupling on Spring Security.

The custom principal is often times returned by a custom `UserDetailsService` that returns an object that implements both `UserDetails` and the custom type. For situations like this, it is useful to create the test user using the custom UserDetailsService. That is exactly what `@WithUserDetails` does.

---

[**`@WithSecurityContext`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withsecuritycontext)

We can create our own annotation that uses the @WithSecurityContext to create any SecurityContext we want. For example, we might create an annotation named @WithMockCustomUser as `@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory.class)`

Comment: I have tried  what you said but it is not resolved. Even with `@WithUserDetails` i still get a nullpointer on `Authentication` @Patel

Comment: Can you share the GitHub link (if possible) with minimal code to reproduce the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419621/spring-boot-webmvctest-how-to-test-controller-method-with-authentication-object

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @WithUserDetails annotation if you have a user persisted in your database initially (or if you create such in @PostConstruct).

Comment: Even when i do this, i still get the nullpointer on `Authentication`

Comment: Put Principal as your controller's argument and remove the Authentication.