# Mock @AuthenticationPrincipal MockMvc with addFilters = false

Tags: unit-testing, spring-security, mockmvc

I am using mockMvc to write unit tests for Controllers in Rest Application.

I am facing challenge in testing below rest End Point -

```
    @GetMapping("/details")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDetails> getUserDetails(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails)
    {       
        
         return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetails);
  
    }
```

As you can see , I need to mock `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to get this rest end Point unit tested
Now the challenge is the unit test class I am using has below skeleton :

```
public class ControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest{

}
```

and **BaseControllerTest** is :

```
    @WebMvcTest
    @ContextConfiguration(
            classes = {
                    TestClass1.class,
                    TestClass2.class,
        
            })
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)//here is a problem 
    @TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    public class BaseControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    }
```

So as you can see all filters are disabled as we are usig `addFilters = false.`

When I debugged the unit tests with eclipse I can see **NO SPRING SECURITY FILTERS** are being added in call chain as `addFilters = true`

I have searched a lot on public forum and it seems using annotations like  `@WithUserDetails` and `@WithMockUser` , it is possible to achieve this.
But these will not work as there is no spring security behind the scenes

Can anybody please help here ?

Comment: `So as you can see all filters are disabled as we are usig addFilters = true` => is just the opposite (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.12.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/AutoConfigureMockMvc.html). Maybe following link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419621/spring-boot-webmvctest-how-to-test-controller-method-with-authentication-object

Comment: @doctore : Its my mistake . Question is corrected