# How do I mock authentications when doing @WebMvcTests with filters enabled?

Tags: java, spring-test

I tested this controller class

```java
@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    private final UserService userService;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public MyRestController(UserService userService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        String userPassBeforeEncoding = user.getPassword();
        String encodedPass = passwordEncoder.encode(userPassBeforeEncoding);
        user.setPassword(encodedPass);
        userService.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

// more methods
```

with this test

```java
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class MyRestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @MockBean
    UserService userService;
    @MockBean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    User mickey;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mickey = new User();
        mickey.setUsername("mickey");
        // more setters

        when(passwordEncoder.encode(anyString())).thenReturn("password");
    }

    @Test
    void addUser() throws Exception {
        var response = mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mickey))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();
        User userFromResponse = objectMapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), User.class);
        assertThat(userFromResponse).isEqualTo(mickey);
        verify(userService, times(1)).save(mickey);
    }

// more tests
```

It works but only as long as I disable filters. I wonder how I test it with filters. Here's my Security config:

```java
@Configuration
@Import(WebMvcConfig.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final UserDao userDao;

    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
            if (user == null) {
                String message = String.format("No user with username %s is found in the database", username);
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(message);
            }
            return user;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) ->
                httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/");
    }
}
```

As you see, the `/users` endpoint doesn't require any credentials, only an authentication (you could argue it should, but it's not the point). That is why `@WithMockUser` alone can't help. How do I mock such an authentication and avoid my tests failing due to 403 "forbidden" (which is what happens if I keep the filters enabled)?

I also tried `@WithUsersDetails`

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.controllers;

// imports

@WebMvcTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyRestControllerTestConfig.class)
class MyRestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @MockBean
    UserService userService;
    @MockBean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    User mickey;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        when(passwordEncoder.encode(anyString())).thenReturn("password");
    }

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = "admin", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "userDetailsServiceMock")
    void addUser() throws Exception {

// ...
```

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.controllers.config;

// imports

@TestConfiguration
public class MyRestControllerTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceMock(UserDetails testAdmin) {
        return username -> testAdmin;
    }

    @Bean
    public User testAdmin() {
        User scrooge = new User();
        scrooge.setUsername("admin");
        scrooge.setPassword("password");
        // irrelevant setters
        scrooge.setEnabledByte((byte) 1);
        scrooge.setAuthorities(Set.of(new Role("USER"),
                new Role("ADMIN")));
        return scrooge;
    }
}
```

However, I still get 403. Even if I include `@WithMockUser` as well

```java
@WebMvcTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyRestControllerTestConfig.class)
@WithUserDetails(value = "admin", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "userDetailsServiceMock")
@WithMockUser(username = "admin")
class MyRestControllerTest {
```

I guess it's no way to mock an authentication after all

Spring also [suggests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withsecuritycontext) `@WithSecurityContext`, but it looks too complex for such a basic scenario. I believe it's not how I should do it

So what are my options? Notice I tried or at least mentioned all solutions listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62800483/22186847)